# Actual size (48x48)px of Icon http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico does > not match specified size (16x16)px?

Tags: manifest

I have a simple react PWA project.

```
public
    index.html
    favicon.ico
    logo-192x192.png
    logo-512x512.png
    manifest.json
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "short_name": "Name",
  "start_url": "/",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#fff",
  "description": "A simply PWA app.",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
        "src": "/logo-192x192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/logo-512x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

**index.html:**

```
...
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
...
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo-192x192.png" />
...
```

But in **Application** warnings:

> Actual size (48x48)px of Icon http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico does
> not match specified size (64x64)px

[image]

**How I can fix this warnings?**

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add other sizes when you know that the current icon is **48x48**.
You can delete them since they are extras. They exist only for guessing the icon's size when one of them is right

`{ "src": "/favicon.ico", "sizes": 48x48", "type": "image/x-icon" },`